# how to download xlsx file in download folder using python

Tags: python, download, onclick, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I've created code for download xlsx file using `xlsxwriter` python library.

File is downloading after onclick event but its not downloading in user's download folder.

its downloading in the project folder where that code file is located. I'm using pathlib library to find the user's download folder.

views.py for download xlsx :

```
def downloadFuelXlsx(request):
    downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
    print(downloads_path)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Fuel.xlsx") 
    print(workbook)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    """ Add a format for the header cells. """ 
    header_format = workbook.add_format(
        {
            "border": 1,
            "bg_color": "#C6EFCE",
            "bold": True,
            "text_wrap": True,
            "valign": "vcenter",
            "indent": 1,
        }
    )

    """ Create Excel"""

    #Create Heading and apply formatting
    heading1 = "Name"
    heading2 = "Fuel Type"
    heading3 = "Cost"

    worksheet.write("A1", heading1, header_format)
    worksheet.write("B1", heading2, header_format)
    worksheet.write("C1", heading3, header_format)

    length = 20 #Set the number as per number of rows required. This will give you 20 rows in data

    #The list inside source should dynamically come from Database
    for r in range(1, length, 1):
        worksheet.data_validation('B'+str(r+1), {'validate': 'list',
                                    'source': ['Petrol', 'Diesel', 'BioFuel'],
                                    })
    workbook.close()
    return workbook
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
      path('download_fuel_xlsx', views.downloadFuelXlsx, name='download_fuel_xlsx'),
]
```

Html Code for onclick download xlsx:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
 <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:25px;color:green;cursor: pointer;"> <a target="_blank" href="{% url 'shouldcost:download_fuel_xlsx' %}"></a></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes there is no reason why  `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Fuel.xlsx")` would create the file in the  `downloads_path` you're not applying it to anything. It appears you just assign it to a variable and print the variable. Therefore the file will create in the `default directory`. Apart from the answer below which should work, setting the `default directory` should also work for you, i.e. `os.chdir(downloads_path)` then `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Fuel.xlsx")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using the downloads_path variable so you aren't opening the workbook in the downloads folder.

Try replacing `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Fuel.xlsx")` with `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f"{downloads_path}/Fuel.xlsx")`